# Install CentOS 5.6 with Cobbler

Tags: pxe-boot, cobbler

I imported centos 5.6 into cobbler and set up all the pxe boot stuff. When I netboot it starts the install, but asks me "What type of media contains the packages to be installed".  I'm given a choice of CDROM,HTTP,NFS,etc.  I want to install from the mirror of the DVD on the cobbler server.

I think I'm missing some high level concepts here.  My goal is to just go through a plain vanilla install at first with all the dialogs, and use the choices I make as a template for a kickstart file.  For the first install I basically just want to use cobbler to PXE boot the CentOS DVD.  This is what I'm doing now:

```
mount -o loop centos.iso /mnt    
cobbler import --name=centos5 --arch=x86_64 --path=/mnt
```

At this point the cd rsyncs to my local drive.

```
cobbler system add --name=myhost comment="Node" --dns-name=myhost.domain.tld --ip-address=192.168.111.201 --mac-addr=00:05:00:21:00:e0  --profile=centos5-x86_64
cobbler sync
```

I boot the system to PXE and begin the CentOS install.  I choose keyboard & language and then I get the dialog "What type of media contains the packages to be installed?".  Choices are 'Local CDROM', 'Hard drive', 'NFS image','FTP','HTTP'.

What do I need to do to get the CentOS install to pull the packages from the cobbler server?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer here. It could be a good follow up to: http://serverfault.com/questions/271184/tips-for-optimizing-rhel-centos-kickstart-workflow

Comment: Yeah I think cobbler/puppet is the popular answer.  So far the best doc I've found for cobbler is: 'man cobbler'.  A lot of the resources out on the web are a little dated.

Comment: I've figured out a bit more.  Cobbler does import the packages and places them in '/var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/name-of-your-distro'.  These are served up by apache (you can browse http://cobblerserver/cobbler).  Point your install to this source using kickstart or the equivalent ... haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably all you need is to add `url --url=$tree` to `/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/default.ks` (or your own kickstart file). It will point to mirrored OS repo, see output of `cobbler report distros` for `Kickstart Metadata` line.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to do the same with Ubuntu, but I guess that's another question.

Comment: I do want to share the actual url line that solved the issue for me:  'url --url=http://cobbler.server.ip/cobbler/ks_mirror/distro-name'.  You can browse http://cobbler.server.ip/cobbler to see what you have.  Or 'ls /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/'

Answer (score 1):

I did this with NFS, try this:

- Install system-config-nfs and system-config-netboot (from yum)
- Start system-config-nfs and share some directory, lets say /srv/
- Copy Centos Installer DVD content into /srv/Centos or just mount it there
- Start system-config-netboot and fill the inputs, in protocol type use NFS for the IP the server's IP where nfs service is running and the directory should be /srv/Centos